# Why is this image inside svg not being displayed?

Tags: svg

Here is the plunkr:

http://jsfiddle.net/6L7utsoe/

```
<body>
<svg height=“200” width=“200”>
    <g id="elem1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <g x="0" id="txt" y="0" height="333.3333333333333" width="255" fill-opacity="1" fill="#aa0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" frames="" mv="true">
            <image x="0" y="0" height="333.3333333333333" width="255" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,URI"></image>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It's an svg image inside two nested  elements. The reason the second  has a bunch of parameters is because it is output after compilation from Angular directive. The html I have in the jsfiddle is what I receive in google chrome. The image reads from base-64 URI. But it fails to load. It could be something really silly as I am new to SVG as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Rathunter/6L7utsoe/1/

You set SVG with some weird quotes on

```
 <svg width="200" height="200"> </svg>
```

and this seemed to break your example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't use the right quotes for your svg width/height:

```
<svg height=“200” width=“200”>
```

instead of

```
<svg height="200" width="200">
```

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/om5bqh92/

Comment: Thank you! How does one end up with a quote like that?

Comment: I don't know, you might of entered it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this SVG header, wrapped around a `<div>` that controls the width, height using CSS (also read up in preserveAspectRatio to find the best option for your design).

```
<body>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
    ...
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```